# Is is possible to determine the local path from url?

Tags: python, apache, url-routing

I have access to apache web server. It is a web service application using Python.

I would like to access a file (100% sure reside in the local which is the web server itself) but I have only the url.

I am thinking of references any setting file of apache web server to determine the absolute local path of the file.

let say I have this kind of url:  http://localhost/service/abc.jpg . So I can parse it to get the filename then obtain the decided local path from setting file.

But.. how about this kind of url: http://localhost/service/imagefile1 . In this case, I have only the url that the filename is not included in the url but still valid url. Is it possible to obtain the absolute local path of the file from url?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Is is possible to determine the local path from url?

The short answer: no.

---

Generally speaking, there is no concrete association between a URL and a file. In fact, there's nothing to say that the data at a given URL exists in a file on any server anywhere.

Comment: I'm guessing that you might need to reverse engineer a site?  If so, if its written in django, look in the urls.py file.  You can also look at the apache mod_rewrite stuff.  I'm not well versed in that, but the server can be set up with rules to translate urls to locations.  Also just poke around

Comment: You might want to comment on the question, so the OP actually sees it.